# Oracle - django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: python, django, oracle

I am trying to run below query
 `MyModel.objects.raw("select id from my_model where id in %s", [(1, 2)])[0]` but getting an error `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number`

When I pass only 1 value in the list in params like `MyModel.objects.raw("select id from my_model where id in %s", [(1)])[0]` then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple values for **in** must be comma separated as in below example.

```
select result from tab1 where col1 in (va1,val2,val3);
```

Comment: i am passing a tuple in the params which is comma separated by its nature

Comment: Make the query string like query = "select id from my_model where id in %s", [(1, 2)])[0]" and then print to see what query is being passed That will give you an idea about the error.

Comment: the query that it is creating looks fine

Comment: Paste it here for confirmation please.